# "No element found using locator..." when performing e2e testing with cucumber

Tags: javascript, protractor, cucumber

I get the folowing failure on several features of Cucumber "NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: By(css selector, h1)"

I have tried to set a bigger timeout in order to give Cucumber more time to find the elements, but it doesn't seem to work

Here are the main components of teh test:
cardTitle.feature:

```
@cardTitle-feature
Feature: See card title
  Display the card title

  @cardTitle-scenario
  Scenario: Card Page
    Given I am on the card page
    When I do nothing
    Then I should see the card title
```

app.steps.ts:

```
// Go to the card - Display the title
Given(/^I am on the card page$/, async () => {
    await page.navigateToCard();
});

When(/^I do nothing$/, () => {
});

Then(/^I should see the card title$/, async () => {
    expect(await page.getCardTitleText()).to.equal('Profile');
});
```

app.po.ts:

```
navigateToCard() {
        this.sleep(3000);
        return browser.get('/card');
    }

getCardTitleText() {
        this.sleep(3000);
        return element(by.css('h1')).getText();
    }
```

card.html:

```
<div class="profile-container">
  <!-- EXAMPLE TOP NAV -->

  <h1>Profile</h1>
...
```

I think that this could happen because "card" may not be accessible without login in the application. If this is the problem, how could I perform a test that logs into the application and then checks the "h1" element?
Thank you!

Comment: not an expert but by.css feels like it searches by css attributes but youre searching for html tags which is its own function https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.By.tagName

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great write up!  Thanks for all the detail, that helps a lot.  Here are my thoughts:

- Don't you need to `await` the sleeps in your page object?  Or promised chain the `sleep` to the `get`, if you're avoiding async functions in your page object for some reason.
- Given that you're using protractor, and presumably this is an angular app, I'm surprised that you would need sleeps at all.  Usually the built in `waitForAngular` that runs as part of every `browser.get` should wait until the page is fully loaded, before continuing
- Your css looks perfect, that should work just fine.  You can locate both html tags and attribute with css.
- I'm assuming `this.sleep` is a method in your page object base class or something?  I was kind of expecting `browser.sleep`.

Btw, I've gotten a lot of mileage out of the `$` and `$$` aliases in protractor, they're so clean.  You could shorten

```
return element(by.css('h1')).getText();
```

To just

```
return $('h1').getText();
```

If you prefer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer Nathaniel! Yes, the method sleep is one that I've created in my page object class, and I use it to solve the "timeout" error and it seems to work. I'm going to try to implement it the way you tell me, using $. I hope I can solve it!